# How do I get my footer and columns and forms within the footer to be responsive properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get my footer to be responsive? Problems: when the screen shrinks down to below 1200px the column on the right side (footer-right) starts getting cut off and the middle columns form input field shrinks down too small. When it gets to approx 750px the middle and left column form under the first column on the left, which is what they are supposed to do but the middle forms input field is only about 1px wide; and the right form is offset too far left instead of in the middle. The first column on the left responsiveness is working properly but not the other two (middle and far right)

The help is greatly appreciated!

```
<footer class="footer-distributed">
<div class="row">
<div class="footer-left col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
<h3>text</h3>
<p class="footer-links">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
                ·
<a href="about.html">About us</a>
                ·
<a href="products.html">Products</a>
                ·
<a href="support.html">Support</a>
                ·
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</p>

<h3>Text</h3>

<p class="footer-links">
<a href="text.html">text</a>
                ·
<a href="text.html">text</a>
                ·
<a href="text.html">text</a>
                ·
<a href="text.html">text</a>

</p>



<p class="footer-company-name"> <a href="http://www.home.com">text</a><span> &copy; text</span></p>


<div class="footer-social">


<ul class="social">
<li>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/text/" class="Facebook">
<i class="ion-social-facebook"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://twitter.com/text" class="Twitter">
<i class="ion-social-twitter"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/text" class="Linkedin">
<i class="ion-social-linkedin"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://text" class="Google Plus">
<i class="ion-social-googleplus"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/text" class="youtube">
<i class="ion-social-youtube"></i>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="form-sub subscribe section-wrapper">
<p class="subscribe-parafoot">
        Sign up for our newsletter
</p>
<p class="subscribe-nowfoot">
        text
</p>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-3 col-sm-push-2">
<form action="" method="post" id="subscribe1">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control border-radius" placeholder="Email address">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn border-radius contactfoot-btn" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>               
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer-right col-sm-3 col-xs-8">
<p>Contact Us</p>
<form action="#" method="post" id="contactForm">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<button>Send</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.footer-distributed .footer-right p{
text-align: center;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 0px 0px 20px 0;
color: #ffffff;
color:  #bebebe;
font: normal 36px 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-right form{
display: inline-block;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-right form input,
.footer-distributed .footer-right form textarea{
display: block;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: none;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color:  #fafafa;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
resize: none;
height: 40px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
font: inherit;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
color:  #4b4b4b;
width: 280px;
padding: 10px;
}

.footer-distributed ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color:  #3e3e3e;
opacity: 1;
}

.footer-distributed ::-moz-placeholder {
color:  #3e3e3e;
opacity: 1;
}

.footer-distributed :-ms-input-placeholder{
color:  #3e3e3e;
opacity: 1;
}


.footer-distributed .footer-right form textarea{
height: 75px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 10px  ;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-right form button{
border-radius: 3px;
background-color:  #00bbff;
color: #ffffff;
border: 0;
padding: 6px 40px;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 18px;
float: right;
letter-spacing: 1px;
height: 42px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-right form button:hover {
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: #ffffff ;
color: #00bbff;
border: 1px solid #00bfff;
padding: 6px 40px;
font-weight: 500;
float: right;
letter-spacing: 1px;
height: 42px;
}


.footer-social .social {
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.footer-social .social li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 15px;
}

.footer-social .social li a {
font-size: 22px;
color: #00bfff;
}


.footer-social .social li:hover {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 15px;
}

.footer-social .social li a:hover {
font-size: 22px;
color: #087aff;
}

#copyright a:hover,
#copyright nav .menu li a:hover {
color: #e4e4e4!important;
}

#copyright a,
#copyright a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-distributed{
background-color: #292c2f;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
width: 100%;
font: bold 16px sans-serif;
padding: 20px 20px 40px;
}


.footer-distributed h3{
color:  #bebebe;
font: normal 36px 'roboto', sans-serif;
margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.footer-distributed .contactfoot-btn:hover {
color: #00bfff;
background: #fff;
border-color: #00bfff;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 18px;
margin-top: 1px;
height: 44px
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
font-size: 18px;
color:  #00bfff;
font-weight: 400;
margin: 0 0 10px;
padding: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
display:inline-block;
line-height: 1.8;
text-decoration: none;
color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a:hover{
display:inline-block;
line-height: 1.8;
text-decoration: none;
color:  #087aff;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
color:  #00bfff;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name span{
color:  #bebebe;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name a{
color: #00bfff;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name a:hover{
color: #087aff;
}


.footer-distributed .subscribe-nowfoot {
color: #eaeaea;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-weight: 300;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.footer-distributed .btn-form:hover,
.footer-distributed .btn-form:active {
border: 1px solid #00bfff;
background-color: #fff;
color: #00bfff;
}

.footer-distributed .custom-sub-btn {
font-size: 18px;
background-color: #00bfff;
color: #fff;
border-color: #00bfff;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin-top: 0px;
height: 43px; 
}

.footer-distributed .custom-sub-btn:hover {
color: #00bfff;
background: #fff;
border-color: #00bfff;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 18px;
margin-top: 0px;
height: 43px
}

.footer-distributed .contactfoot-btn {
font-size: 18px;
background-color: #00bfff;
color: #fff;
border-color: #00bfff;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin-top: 1px;
height: 44px; 
}

.footer-distributed .contactfoot-btn:hover {
color: #00bfff;
background: #fff;
border-color: #00bfff;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 18px;
margin-top: 1px;
height: 44px
}

.footer-distributed ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color:  #3e3e3e;
opacity: 1;
}

.footer-distributed ::-moz-placeholder {
color:  #3e3e3e;
opacity: 1;
}

.footer-distributed :-ms-input-placeholder{
color:  #3e3e3e;
opacity: 1;
}


.form-sub {
margin: 60px;
}


.form-sub form input {
height: 44px;
resize: none;
}


.form-sub .custom-sub-btn{
background-color: #00bfff;
color: #fff;
border-color: #00bfff;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin-top: 1px;
}

.form-sub .custom-sub-btn:hover{
color: #00bfff;
background: #fff;
border-color: #00bfff;
font-weight: 500;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.subscribe-parafoot {
color: #bebebe;
font-size: 170%;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 28px;
margin: -70px 0 20px;
text-align: center;
}


.subscribe-now {
color: #727272;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 28px;
margin: 0px 0 20px;
text-align: center;
}

.subscribe-para {
color: #1c1c1c;
font-size: 170%;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 28px;
margin: 0px 0 20px;
text-align: center;
}

.form-control {
max-width: auto;
margin: 1px;
font-weight: 300;
color: #6a6a6a;
}

.form .input-group{
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Media Queries
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer .copyright {
    text-align: center;
    }
    #footer .social {
    text-align: center;
    }
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a FULLY responsive footer, you wont want to hardcode any widths for elements inside the footer (or the footer itself). I saw that the CSS selector below has a width attribute of 280px:

```
footer-distributed .footer-right form input,
.footer-distributed .footer-right form textarea {...
  width: 280px;
...}
```

I'm led to believe that this property would make that field stubborn when resizing the screen.

Since you are using media queries, trying finding a percentage that works for the textarea and input, and then adjust that percentage on the screen resize. That way it will still have a breakpoint, but by dynamic in its behavior up to that point.

Hope this helps.
Sebastian

Comment: Yah, I had it without at first and tried adding it so the field wouldn't shrink so small into pretty much nothing

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I copied down your code but had a hard time seeing what exactly you were going for layout wise.

Comment: no luck yet. basically I've tried putting three divs in the footer and I want them to align side by side. I have one div on the left, middle (center) and right. the left side is basically the navigation and social, the middle is a subscribe form (just email field and button) with text above it. and the right side is a contact us form with just the text contact us and below it an email input field and below that an area for text. so far I have managed to get the the center to align beside the left but the right side keeps going below the div on the far left

Comment: I'm also trying to make them responsive so that when the screen shrinks the look good, for example at a certain point they would all align one under the other